# Using a ClickHandler with a child of Element

Tags: java, gwt

I need to add an Anchor with a specific ClickHandler into an Element.
But the onClick(...) method of my Anchor is never called.

How can I fix that?

```
Element th = DOM.createTH();
Anchor link = new Anchor();
link.setText("my link");
link.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      Window.alert("Clicked!");
    }
});
th.appendChild(link.getElement());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not tried implementing it in such way but, I do in this way and it is working properly.

```
final Element link = DOM.createAnchor();
final Element th = DOM.createTH();
link.setInnerText("my link");
link.setAttribute("style", "cursor:pointer;");
DOM.sinkEvents(link, Event.ONCLICK);
DOM.setEventListener(link, new EventListener() {
      public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
          Window.alert("Clicked!");     
      }
});
th.appendChild(link);
```

I think this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly fine (except setText method on an Element :-P)