# Why Handler doesn't work while Listener does his job?

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling, listener

I struggle to catch events after famous DOM.appendChild. After many attempts of use handlers I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080250/using-a-clickhandler-with-a-child-of-element) where @Õzbek did the job via listener.
And now I don't get it why "listener" works while "handler" not. 
As an example in code:

```
Button button = new Button("Test button");

DOM.appendChild(getElement(), button.getElement());
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        GWT.log("this doesn't work");        
    }
});

DOM.sinkEvents(button.getElement(), Event.ONCLICK);
DOM.setEventListener(button.getElement(), new EventListener() {
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        GWT.log("this works perfectly!");
    }
});
```

the listener will be working but handler not.

1. **So where is difference beetwen them?**
2. **And how to force handler to work?**
3. **Is there are some way to do this on handlers ?**

I'm trying to understand the difference between listeners and handlers. [I read these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725241/whats-the-difference-between-event-listeners-handlers-in-java) which shows that there is no big difference but I still don't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button is a Widget not an element, and if you add it as an element to the dom you would lose the events. You can either append it to the RootPanel:
`RootPanel.get().add(button)` if you want to use the handler.

if you want to use the element not the widget you can use `DOM.createButton()`, and use the listener.

Answer (score 2):

`setEventListener` of widgets is only called when they are "attached" (to a parent widget, which is itself attached, or delayed until it is attached), and you never "attach" the button.

With an explicit `serEventListener` you completely bypass the widget internals (and lifecycle). You could actually just use a `ButtonElement` in this case.

TL;DR: don't do that, it's a symptom of a broken design.

Comment: But in some cases you do not have other option for instance if you would like to extend TextBox and add inside a button for showing some helper, the listener is only one option, am I right ?

Comment: You don't "extends a textbox and add a button", you compose a textbox and a button inside a composite widget.